# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Tags: android, build

I have a problem with running the application
When I run my real or virtual phone show me this message
[image]

This my app code
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enable the multidex in your app

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
          ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    packagingOptions {
       ....
    }

    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

    dependencies {
             ...
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    }
```

also you must change your manifest file. In your manifest add the MultiDexApplication class from the multidex support library to the application element like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
   <application
       ...
       android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
       ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Or if your app uses extends the Application class, you can override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex.

```
   @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Comment: Look at the Answer Below  its not work ,  please help me

Comment: Remove  attachBaseContext() in your main Activity, If you havent used Application class then dont put that code , Just add in manifest file

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'    change your :appcompat-v7: version to 22.2.0' and  gms:play-services: version to 8.1.0'

Comment: can you upload  video on your chanel on youtube for how to fix this problem

Comment: Just change your gradle file as my posted ans thats enough